# New cookie value not taken into account without refreshing page

Tags: php, cookies

There is a specific page on my website that reset a cookie value, and echo the new value later in the code execution.

```
setcookie('notifications_count', 0, time() + (365*24*60*60), '/');
```

and later :

```
<?php
if (isset($_COOKIE['notifications_count']) && $_COOKIE['notifications_count'] != 0)
echo $_COOKIE['notifications_count'];
?>
```

My problem is that it looks to me like the new cookie value won't be taken into account until I refresh the page. Is that the correct behaviour ?
How can I push the new value to replace the old one without refreshing the page ?

My side-solution would be to force a page refresh with header but I would rather not extend the loading duration of the page, to keep the website responsive.

Comment: No it won't, that's how cookies work.... $_COOKIE is populated by the SAPI before your PHP script starts to execute; and `setcookie()` is preparing the response headers to send the cookie to the browser ready for subsequent requests.... you can set $_COOKIE manually within your script if you need the value set immediately (it is just an array after all), but you still need setcookie() if that value is to be sent back to the browser

Comment: I understand. Since it just affects one specific page, I feel setting $_COOKIE manually would be better than redirecting the user with header while the page loads. Thank you for your explanation

Comment: When setting a cookie value manually, do I just go with `$_COOKIE['test'] = 0` or do I need to specify the cookie duration/path aswell so it doesn't mess up the original cookie ?

Comment: The `$_COOKIE` superglobal is a simple PHP array; keys/values, nothing more than that... it doesn't know about domains or paths or durations or anything else